# angular error when redirect using $window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to redirect to other page on angular after posting data to API,
I typed this code:

```
$scope.Proceed = function () {
        DataService.InsertPerson($scope.p)
        .then(function success(data) {
            $scope.p.ID = data.data;
            var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/#/show/person/";
            $window.location.href =  url + data.data; //adding ID to url
        });
    };
```

the page redirected correctly , But Angular Throws an error:

[Error: $rootScope:infdig 
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function()%7Bvar%20b%3Dp(a);if(b!%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%26%26(r.$modelValue%3D%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%7C%7Cb%3D%3D%3Db))%7Br.$modelValue%3Dr.$$rawModelValue%3Db;B%3Dvoid%200;for(var%20c%3Dr.$formatters,d%3Dc.length,e%3Db;d--;)e%3Dc%5Bd%5D(e);r.$viewValue!%3D%3De%26%26(r.$$updateEmptyClasses(e),r.$viewValue%3Dr.$$lastCommittedViewValue%3De,r.$render(),%5Cr%5Cnr.$$runValidators(b,e,A))%7Dreturn%20b%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22Name%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function()%7Bvar%20b%3Dp(a);if(b!%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%26%26(r.$modelValue%3D%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%7C%7Cb%3D%3D%3Db))%7Br.$modelValue%3Dr.$$rawModelValue%3Db;B%3Dvoid%200;for(var%20c%3Dr.$formatters,d%3Dc.length,e%3Db;d--;)e%3Dc%5Bd%5D(e);r.$viewValue!%3D%3De%26%26(r.$$updateEmptyClasses(e),r.$viewValue%3Dr.$$lastCommittedViewValue%3De,r.$render(),%5Cr%5Cnr.$$runValidators(b,e,A))%7Dreturn%20b%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22name@email.com%22%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function()%7Bvar%20b%3Dp(a);if(b!%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%26%26(r.$modelValue%3D%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%7C%7Cb%3D%3D%3Db))%7Br.$modelValue%3Dr.$$rawModelValue%3Db;B%3Dvoid%200;for(var%20c%3Dr.$formatters,d%3Dc.length,e%3Db;d--;)e%3Dc%5Bd%5D(e);r.$viewValue!%3D%3De%26%26(r.$$updateEmptyClasses(e),r.$viewValue%3Dr.$$lastCommittedViewValue%3De,r.$render(),%5Cr%5Cnr.$$runValidators(b,e,A))%7Dreturn%20b%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%22012345678%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function()%7Bvar%20b%3Dp(a);if(b!%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%26%26(r.$modelValue%3D%3D%3Dr.$modelValue%7C%7Cb%3D%3D%3Db))%7Br.$modelValue%3Dr.$$rawModelValue%3Db;B%3Dvoid%200;for(var%20c%3Dr.$formatters,d%3Dc.length,e%3Db;d--;)e%3Dc%5Bd%5D(e);r.$viewValue!%3D%3De%26%26(r.$$updateEmptyClasses(e),r.$viewValue%3Dr.$$lastC)

I tryed $location but same results.

thank you for your time

Comment: which  router are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a redirection with `$window.location.href` you can use AngularJS [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to change the URL and add it to the history stack:

```
$location.url('/show/person/' +  data.data);
```

Or:

```
$location.path('/show/person/' +  data.data);
```

Both methods are `getter` / `setter`:

- `$location.url` returns the entire URL after the slash, including
  search string parameters and change path, search and hash, when called with parameter and return `$location`.
- `$location.path` returns the part of the URL after the slash not including search string parameters and change path when called with parameter and return `$location`.

Comment: After changing the code and using $location, Angular route to default page.

Comment: Have to check the new url is well formed and exists in your routes, and also check that the `data.data` returned from the success function is a valid valid value..

Comment: See that I have used `/#/show/person/` similar to you.. Try with: `$location.url('/show/person/' +  data.data);`

Comment: _Have to check the new url is well formed and exists in your routes_ yes the same url is redirect with '$window.location.href' ,  and I testing using hard coded value '$location.url('/#/show/person/' + "1");'

Comment: The problem was solved after using **$location.path('/show/person/' + data.data)** WITHOUT **#**

Comment: Updated the answer.. Both methods are similar and should work. `$location.path` returns the part of the URL after the slash not including search string parameters and `$location.url` returns the entire URL after the slash, including search string parameters